# Jlink Commander doesn't find LPC4088 microcontroller on my homemade PCB

Tags: jtag, lpc, j-link

I just finished a homemade PCB with a LPC4088 microcontroller and some other components. When I connected my board to the J-link EDU probe over JTAG connector and start Jlink Commander, Cortex-M4 microprocessor inside LPC4088 isn't found like microprocessor is found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLbZj-o_odk).

If everything was correct J-link Commander should find the Cortex-M4 microcontroller so I assume that I made mistake when I was designing the schematics.

I doubt that I made mistake with a power section of the board. The mistake is probably part of JTAG connections which I am quite new to. Yoou might want to open the image in new tab and zoom in in order to better see the schematics.

This is my first MCU board and I really have to make it work...

[image]

Comment: Did you try connecting via SWD? That would use only two lines. Also, try measuring the +3,3V voltage.

Comment: I see. So SWD is less error exposed...